# My Bitbucket pipeline never stops after completing the integration test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, bitbucket, integration-testing, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm running integration testing in the bitbucket pipeline. To run the integration test I need to run the project first then run the karma to test my test cases. But after the test is completed my pipeline runs endlessly. Because I think project run is an endless process, That's why it never stops running.

But if I try to kill the process. It shows the status failed, even after all the test cases are passed. So is there any process to stop my pipeline without getting the failed result?

Here is the bitbucket conf:

```
image: zenika/alpine-chrome:with-node

pipelines:
  branches:
    T13069-unit-test-implementation-in-mandate-assignment:
    - step:
        name: Test
        caches:
          - node
        services:
          - postgres
        script:
          - npm run install-all
          - npx cds deploy
          - npm run watch && npm run test-assignment

definitions:
  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: cm
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```